# What is the difference between `ptr = (int *) realloc(ptr,sizeof(int));` and `ptr = (int *) realloc(ptr,sizeof(int)*m);`?

Tags: c, realloc

This is the code with extra m no of memory reallocation:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n,m,*ptr;
    printf("Enter the number of variables you want to add in array : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ptr = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the value of element %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i]);
    }

    printf("\nYour array is : ");

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",ptr[i]);
    }

    printf("\nEnter the number of variables you want to add in array : ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    **ptr = (int *) realloc(ptr,sizeof(int)*m);**

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the value of element %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&ptr[n+i]);
    }

    printf("\nYour array is : ");

    for (int i = 0; i < (n+m); i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",ptr[i]);
    }
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

and the next code is without particular no of memory allocation:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n,m,*ptr;
    printf("Enter the number of variables you want to add in array : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    ptr = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the value of element %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\nYour array is : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",ptr[i]);
    }
    printf("\nEnter the number of variables you want to add in array : ");
    scanf("%d",&m);
    ptr = (int *) realloc(ptr,sizeof(int));
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter the value of element %d : ", i+1);
        scanf("%d",&ptr[n+i]);
    }
    printf("\nYour array is : ");
    for (int i = 0; i < (n+m); i++)
    {
        printf("%d  ",ptr[i]);
    }
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

These two code is giving me same output in vs code, with out any runtime error nor any problem. so my question is,

1. Why should I specify `ptr = (int *) realloc(ptr,sizeof(int)*m);` in spite of `ptr = (int *) realloc(ptr,sizeof(int));`?
2. And how much memory exactly the second one allocating? Yes, it should be about one `int`, but why then it's being able to take value more than one / the doubt is still there... for me

**UPDATE**: ok, I am just simplifying the doubt. Suppose I have a program that allocates 10 `int` memory for an array. Now, I am passing 15 value to this array using any kind of loop to store them. After that, I am printing them one by one. And what happened then? This code just worked well! HOW? Is it actually allocating 10 `int` mem, or even more?

Comment: The answer of your second part is exactly stated in the [manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3p.html) or description in C standard. The allocated size is what you passed as `size` parameter. It is exactly as many bytes as **one** single `int` variable takes. The value depends on the size of `int` on your computer. Where do you have some doubts with that?

Comment: Compile and run the program with an address sanitizer enabled (eg: `gcc -fsanitize=address -g ...`), and see if your code still works...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```c
ptr = (int *) realloc(ptr,sizeof(int)*(n+m));
```

since you want enough space for `n+m` `int` values.

Comment: @Souvik: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: I'm guessing you asked what happens if you don't allocate enough. Hopefully, your program crashes with a protection violation in short order, rather than crashing in a weird way later. Or worse, producing bad outputs